# How to get Websphere server Runtime Base Directory Path

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, websphere

I am developing a Eclipse plugin and I need to access the .class files generated from the JSPs using my plugin. I was able to get the Tomcat Runtime base directory using the following code

```
TomcatServer s = (TomcatServer) ServerCore.getServers()[0].loadAdapter(TomcatServer.class, monitor);
s.getRuntimeBaseDirectory();
```

Is there any way I can access the Websphere server Runtime base directory like this?

Comment: I don't know what APIs there may be to get these, but keep in mind in tWAS there are three potential paths to JSP class files depending on 
a) JspBatchCompiler was used 
b) deferServletLoad is true 
c) deferServletLoad is false.

Comment: In these scenarios can the output path change from one to another? Is there a way to change the output path from the IDE server settings?